# JMeter - Webdriver error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, kernel32

This error:

- [jmeter log](http://pastebin.com/1dQsRhaU),

appears everytime I run a testscript in Jmeter. 
But everything works...

It is just this error that appears everytime in log after the actual script had run.

Can I ignore this error? Or will it influences my test?

**Jmeter:**  2.13
**Java:**   1.8.0.45
**Jmeter Plugin :** 1.3 (Standard,Extras,ExtraLibs, Webdriver)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is due to missing jar that contains :

- com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32

You should be able to download it with its dependency here:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330platformjar.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330jar.htm

And put it in jmeter/lib folder.

See a full tutorial on this at:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Ok, should I cpoy the  jar in lib or anywhere else? I can't find that value in System property. But I use Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Copy it in jmeter/lib yes

Comment: You are right. I'm not getting this error anymore. But after I copy the jar in lib and start JMeter as admin I got a new error: http://pastebin.com/HwCxmEbJ . So download this jar here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna325jar.htm and copy it in lib too. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me just helped changing

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

From 1.7 to 1.8 for source and target