# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32 Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently using Selenium 2.53 for running execution. I have Java jdk 1.8.121. While quitting the browser i.e using the driver.quit() function, I keep getting the NoClassDefFoundError. The stack is as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$2(UnixProcess.java:246)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.quit(FirefoxBinary.java:246)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.quit(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:194)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.quit(FirefoxDriver.java:364)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.stopClient(FirefoxDriver.java:310)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:529)
 [java]     at com.obp.selenium.Framework.CommonActions.executeTestCases(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at com.obp.selenium.Framework.DriverScript.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 [java]     ... 25 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

What is the solution available? I browsed through some issues where they stated is as a JNA error. But I am unable to solve the issue on the suggestions.

Comment: Which FF version are you using, and As you are using selenium 2.53, i take you are not using geckodriver

Comment: You might be missing some jars as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function

Comment: I am using Firefox 34 under compulsion. Also the jars are missing. But the problem appear intermittently. It is not a fixed issue.

Comment: I'd suggest download fresh sel;enium 2.53 jars from seleniumHQ and add them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter - Webdriver error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562937/jmeter-webdriver-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-sun-jna-platform)